# How does ping resolve ip addresses?

Tags: tcp, dns, ping, network-protocols, application-layer

The `ping` utility works above the network layer and DNS works in the application layer.

If we try `ping www.google.com`, how does it resolve the IP address of GOOGLE since the DNS is above these layers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ICMP (the *protocol*) may operate above IP, alongside TCP but a `ping` *program* itself almost certainly still uses the normal methods for name resolution, be that DNS, hosts file or `resolv.conf`.

For example, the `ping` program located [here](https://gist.github.com/kbaribeau/4495181) calls on `gethostbyname()` to turn DNS names into IP addresses.

Comment: Do you know if ping tries to resolve dns name into ip each time the ping is sent or just at the beginning. In other words - does [ping google.com -n 10] will ask dns for resolving google.com 10 times, or only once when it starts?

Comment: @guitar_freak, it depends on the implementation. However, I'm not sure that allowing for rapidly changing IP addresses for a given host name would be a particularly useful feature. The one I just looked up resolved *once* on program start, not before every single ICMP packet.

Comment: How does ping know what 'normal' method to use? Afaik, ping implements resolv.c from the libc.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly on windows computers, ping also uses LLMNR ([Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb878128)) to perform hostname resolution.
A host may be pinged just fine while other services still fail if a computer is only known by LLMNR and the failing service relies on DNS.
Vice versa: DNS may work but ping fails

Answer (score 0):

Hostnames are still resolved through DNS, after that ping uses ICMP for the actual communication. You can try changing the DNS configs to invalid servers and see that ping won't work with hostnames.